# How to access dictionary elements in a list in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm trying to understand about dictionaries and list in Python.

Assume that I have a list which contains 3 dictionaries
Ex. `item_list = [price,stock,quantity]`

price, stock and quantity are the dictionaries here. Each dictionary has few key-value pairs like

```
price = {'toys':25,'clothes':[12,15,20]}
```

I know to access individual elements, I can use a for loop with the keys specified like:

```
for item in item_list:
        print item['toys']
```

How do I access the elements without directly mentioning the key in the for loop?

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: You can get a list of keys by item.keys()

Comment: @Eenvincible - I would be inputting those values to other variable. Print is just an example I gave. So would not want to hardcode the key.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over a dictionary just like you can iterate over a list.

```
for item in item_list:
    for key in item:
        print item[key]
```

In a sense, you're still mentioning the keys, but you're not referencing them explicitly by their value.

If you're just interested in the values you can use the values() method:

```
for item in item_list:
    for key in item.values():
        print item[key]
```

My preferred way to iterate over dictionaries though is with items, which returns a tuple of key, value pairs.

```
for item in item_list:
    for key, value in item.items():
        print key, value
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for d in item_list:
    for i in d.values():
       print i
```

You could also call d.items() and get back tuples of (key, value) if you wanted access to both.
Additionally if you don't care about readability you could use this to get a list of all the values accross the dicts in your list.

[x for y in (i.values() for i in item_list) for x in y]

You can also use: `[d for i in item_list for d in i.values()]` to get the values and flatten them into a list (though yours would still be nested because of clothes' value being a list.

Finally you can merge the dictionaries into one if they have distinct keys:

```
joint_mapping = dict([d for i in item_list for d in i.items()])
```

or if they don't have unique values you can use the below code to produce a dict of lists of values. :

```
for k, v in [d for i in item_list for d in i.items()]:
     new_d[k] = new_d.get(k, [])+[v]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this:

```
for item in item_list:
  for key, value in item.iteritems():
    print key, value
```

Answer (score 0):

Let us say, you have a list like this

```
prices_list = [{'toys':25,'clothes':[12,15,20]},{'toys':35,'clothes':[12,15,20]}]
```

And you would like to get the value corresponding to `toys`, but without specifying the name in the for loop. So, you can use [`operator.itemgetter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) like this

```
from operator import itemgetter
getter = itemgetter("toys")
print [getter(item) for item in prices_list]
# [25, 35]
```

The same can be used like this

```
total = 0
for item in prices_list:
    total += getter(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned :

> @Eenvincible - I would be inputting those values to other variable.
>    Print is just an example I gave. So would not want to hardcode the key.

I think you can do your trick using for loop as mentioned in other answers.

```
for item in item_list:
    for key in item:
        print item[key]
        tempvariable = item[key]
        .... do something here.
```

If you want to assign each value to a seperate variable, you should:

```
 - First, assign that variables to any insignificant value EX: **None** or *""*
 - Then,  dynamically use the for loop to reassign each variable to new value using if condition or thier index.
```

**EX:**

```
price_toys , price_clothes , stock_toys , stock_clothes  = None , None , None , None
for item in item_list:
     for key in item:
           tempvariable = item[key]
           # condition to choose which varible will be set to the current value.
           if item == "price" and key == "toys":
                  price_toys  = tempvariable
            # and so on
```